# windows WSH compare dateLastModified

Tags: date, jscript, wsh

I'm trying to synchronize .doc files, based on their dateLastModified Attribute, using WSH and Jscript.

I have a folderObject called src and a string to destination, called dstPath.

the src folderObject points to a remote server. But i tried with both folders on local disk, with same results

```
var fso = WSH.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
src = fso.getFolder(srcPath);

for(e = new Enumerator(src.files) ; !e.atEnd() ; e.moveNext() ){

//only word docs
if ( e.item().Type == "Document Microsoft Word 97 - 2003"){

    try{
        f= fso.getFile(dstPath + e.item().Name)

        if ((f.DateLastModified) != (e.item().DateLastModified)){
            WSH.echo(f.Name + "\t" +  f.DateLastModified + "\t" +  e.item().DateLastModified)
            e.item().copy(dstPath);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is some sample output :

```
test1.doc   Tue Jun 10 11:10:04 UTC+0200 2014   Tue Jun 10 11:10:04 UTC+0200 2014
```

as you can see, both dates are the same, but the != operator still returns true, and the file get copied anyway...

I also notice that typeof(file.dateLastModified) returns "date" but this is not a real Jscript date object, since I cannot do f.DateLastModified.getTime()   it returns nothing.

Any hints on what's wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
if ((f.DateLastModified) != (e.item().DateLastModified)){
```

applies the != operator to two different (date) **objects**. According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky6fyhws%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

> Values are considered equal if they are identical strings, numerically
>   equivalent numbers, **the same object**, identical Boolean values, or (if
>   different types) they can be coerced into one of these situations.
>   (emphasis mine)

These objects may not be 'full' JScript dates - I couldn't call methods on them either - but you'll need to compare their **values** to avoid unecessary copies. I'd use + to force a comparison of the underlying milliseconds.

Evidence:

```
// two different Date objects with the same value
var d1 = new Date(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
var d2 = new Date(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
WSH.Echo("d1:", d1);
WSH.Echo("d2:", d2);
WSH.Echo("Different objects:");
WSH.Echo("  d1 == d2:", (d1 == d2).toString());
WSH.Echo("  d1 != d2:", (d1 != d2).toString());
WSH.Echo("Same (numerical) value:");
WSH.Echo("  +d1:", +d1);
WSH.Echo("  +d2:", +d2);
WSH.Echo("  d1 - d2:", d1 - d2);
WSH.Echo("  +d1 == +d2:", (+d1 == +d2).toString());
```

output:

```
d1: Sun Mar 3 04:05:06 UTC+0100 1901
d2: Sun Mar 3 04:05:06 UTC+0100 1901
Different objects:
  d1 == d2: false
  d1 != d2: true
Same (numerical) value:
  +d1: -2172171293993
  +d2: -2172171293993
  d1 - d2: 0
  +d1 == +d2: true
```

Comment: Thanks ! that's working :) I'll keep the +d1 trick in mind to do the cast